# How to get hold of data in JSON file fetched from an API when one of the object name is a number

Tags: node.js, json, api, backend, endpoint

I am making a corona virus counting website. So I used an API that fetches the details as a JSON. [Endpoint link](https://api.covid19tracking.narrativa.com/api/2021-05-06/country/india)
When I am copying the path for a specific state, it comes up as something like

```js
var ind_total = covidData.dates['2021-05-06'].countries.India.regions[1].today_confirmed
```

But while running the server in node it is not able to recognise ['2021-05-06'] this part `TypeError: Cannot read property '2021-05-06' of undefined`

I have attached picture of JSON file starting point. Pls help. Thanks in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmVwQ.png)

Comment: likely your covidData.dates is not ready yet. Show a minimal code example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The error here means that `covidData.dates` is undefined, make sure to check your `covidData` object first, to see what's in there